# Выбор поля + php

Tags: php

HTML:

```
   <select name='pol'>
   <option value="m">Мужской</option>
   <option value="f">Женский</option>
   </select>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['pol'])) { 
$pol=$_POST['pol']; 
if ($pol =='') { 
unset($pol);
} 
}
```

Как сделать, чтоб если переменная pol не равна m или f, выводило ошибку?(как не будет равна? Кто-нибудь может зайти в "Посмотреть код" и отредактировать)

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "выводило ошибку"?

Comment: Пишите в php-коде сравнение с m и f, если не равно — выводите что вам нужно. Сравнения вы писать, судя по примеру, уже умеете, выводить что-нибудь, скорее всего, тоже — что-то я не понял, в чём проблема

Comment: я имею в виду выводить "Ошибка"